# Alternative views instead of Stackviews for android versions lower to android 3.0

Tags: android

I am trying to implement `StackView` behaviour in my application but I believe this widget is only available from android 3.0 onwards. I am an intermediate developer for android OS and hence have limited knowledge on customized views.

Could some one please provide some pointers as to how i can achieve `Stackview` in android 2.2/2.3?

Comment: At least a couple of the previous questions you have asked have been answered in full. Please mark the answers given as correct if they were, or add a comment explaining what issues you had with the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no component in the SDK with this exact functionality prior to API Level 11 (3.0), so you will need to create your own custom View to get the desired effect.

The easiest/quickest way would be to create a custom view that extends FrameLayout since children of a FrameLayout automatically stack on top of each other and your custom view will inherit this behaviour. 
You'll also want to override the way children are laid out so that you adjust the x and y position of the children depending on where they are in the stack.

You will have to make your own methods to go to the next/previous view - you'd have to do this by re-ordering the the child views (remove them all, then add them back in the new order).

The solution I've described doesn't include the view recycling you get with AdapterViews, so wouldn't be suitable for a large number of stacked items.

Alternatively, find the StackView source code and copy it into your project, though this will probably also involve copying a large amount of other Android classes into your project, since StackView will undoubtedly access private members of super-classes that are only accessible from the widgets package (without Reflection).

Comment: Thanks Joesph...But copying the stackview source code would only work for android 3.0 or above rght?

Comment: No, it could certainly work on earlier versions (unless it relies on native functionality that has changed), but you would have to copy all the classes that StackView references that are in 3.0 but not in earlier versions into your project. So it would involve a lot of copying classes into your project, and a lot of editing these classes to change the references to your versions of the classes and not the Android ones which don't exist.

Comment: Basically don't go down the straight copying route, it is probably more work than looking at the StackView code, understanding what it does, and then making your own; because you will need to copy and edit quite a lot of files in order to make it actually work.

Comment: thanks.You saying it should be possible to create stack views even in android versions below 3.0?The reason I am asking this is, I googled today for possible ways to create such custom views(most of which mentioned FrameLayout like you did) , but my main concern is that:First,I want to make sure that this is do-able in android 2.2/2.3 and secondly how would the Framelayout & its child views handle the UI(need to show the previous screen which was in stack as transparent and of reduced size and the current one overlayed on top of it) .Can you elaborate/provide some pointers please?Thanks...