# StackView for Android 2

Tags: android

I've found that StackView is missing in compatibility package and can be used only since android 3.

I also looked at the source code of this widget and it seems to be impossible to integrate it with lower versions of android because of dozen of dependencies from new android framework.

What you can reccomend? Is there any attempts to migrate StackView to lower versions of android? After first look at the source code I can say that this view is extremely complex, so implementing the same thing from scratch may be tricky.

So what can you reccomend me, how I can implement the same view in the most simple way?

Comment: Try this link : - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5544324/645776