# how to create custom stackview for android 2.2 or 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, stackview

I need to create a custom stack view for my project and I saw that its not readily available for android versions prior to honeycomb.
If anyone can help me understanding how I can create a custom stackview  for froyo or gingerbread.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544112/alternative-views-instead-of-stackviews-for-android-versions-lower-to-android-3/5544324#5544324

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the tutorial here? 
http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html